# Firestore missing permission on query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to only allow authenticated users to access content which they own.
Bellow is the firestore rules that I am using.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}
```

This is the query getting the user profile by username.

```
  const document = await Firebase.firestore().collection('users').where('username', '==', username).get()
  await document.forEach(doc => {
    context.commit('SET_PROFILE', doc.data())
  })
```

It returns:

```
FirebaseError: "Missing or insufficient permissions."
```

But the simulation is allowed. What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule and your query need to match up. The rule says that a certain path is allowed, yet in the query you fetch all users with a certain username.

Just fetch `Firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).get()`